# Select creationDate from CloudKit record

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, cloudkit

I'm trying to fill a cell with title and subtitle. Title with the field and detail with the CreationDate from the record.

I am trying the following but I am getting a no member 'ObjectForKey'

var objects = CKRecord

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"
    var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell?
    if (cell != nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    let object = objects[indexPath.row]
    cell!.textLabel!.text = object.objectForKey("Notes") as? String
    cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = object.creationDate.objectForKey("Notes") as? String
    return cell!
}
```

Comment: What type of objects are in your `objects` array? In other words, what type of object is `object`?

Comment: And why are you trying to get the "Notes" key from the creation date?

Comment: var objects = [CKRecord]() is my objects. its an array from cloud kit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is from this line:

```
cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = object.creationDate.objectForKey("Notes") as? String
```

For some reason you are trying to get the "Notes" key from the record's creation date (which is an `NSDate`.

Just get the `creationDate` as an `NSDate`. Then use an `NSDateFormatter` to format the date into a string you can assign to the `detailTextLabel.text`.